# Deploying extensions plugin version 4.0 in RTC server 3.0.13

Tags: plugins, version, rtc

I have developed a rtc extension plugin using rtc server version 4.0.

Is it possible to deploy this plugin in RTC server version 3.0.13?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It mainly depends on your plugin extension definition in term of plugins minimum version required:
(as illustrated in [this thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/103158/rtc-extensions-problem))

[image: minimum versions]

It would be best to build that extension plugin in RTC3, and then try to deploy it on a RTC4 server.